# array_multisort not working PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Please i need your help. I want to sort the array into an ascending order by priority time.

Heres is the array

```
Array
(
    [process] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => p1
                    [burst_time] => 2
                    [priority_time] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => p2
                    [burst_time] => 2
                    [priority_time] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => p3
                    [burst_time] => 2
                    [priority_time] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I tried this code but doesn't work for me. Thank you in advanced :)

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $mid[$key]  = $row;
}
array_multisort($mid, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Comment: `$data` and `$mid` arrays are identical.

Comment: You want `$mid[$key]  = $row['priority_time'];` and probably want `foreach` over `$data['process']`.

Comment: I got this error when I try your code. array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

You're using `array_multisort` but you don't need to sort in multiple dimensions. A simple `usort` is enough:

```
$data = array(
    "process" => array(
        array(
            "name" => p1,
            "burst_time" => 2,
            "priority_time" => 3
        ), array(
            "name" => p2,
            "burst_time" => 2,
            "priority_time" => 4
        ), array(
            "name" => p3,
            "burst_time" => 2,
            "priority_time" => 1
        )
    )
);

usort($data["process"], "sort_by_priority_time");

function sort_by_priority_time($a, $b) {
    return $a["priority_time"] - $b["priority_time"];
}
```

Comment: I got this error. Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sort_by_priority_time' not found or invalid function name

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Thank you guys for your help.

I changed it to. And finally it works.

```html
foreach ($data['process'] as $key => $row) {
    $mid[$key]  = $row;
}
array_multisort($mid, SORT_ASC, $data['process'] );
```